# What is right to do to maintain the principle of inheritance polymorphism?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

What is the to do?
to save a specific edge property to square use the rectangle property?

```
    public Square(double edge) : base(edge, edge)
    {
    }
```

OR

```
    public Square(double edge) : base(edge, edge)
    {
        Edge = edge;
    }
```

---

```
    public Rectangle(double width, double height)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
    }
```

Comment: `Edge` is misleading to me; *which* edge does it represent? A square still has a width and a height, even though they're the same. No need for a square to now have `Edge` `Width` and `Height`. Just use the properties from the base class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not really matter whether you add a new `Edge` property in `Square`, but there is something more important than this. And that is consistency.

If your classes are immutable, then good. But if your classes are mutable, you need to be consistent with the three (or two if you decided not to add `Edge`) properties in `Square`. When width changes, height should also change. When you change `Edge`, both `Width` and `Height` should change.

```
class Square : Rectangle {
    public override double Width {
        get { return base.Width; }
        set { 
            base.Width = value; 
            base.Height = value;
        }
    }

    public override double Height {
        get { return base.Height; }
        set { 
            base.Width = value; 
            base.Height = value;
        }
    }

    public double Edge {
        get { return Width; }
        set {
            base.Width = value; 
            base.Height = value;
        }
    }

    public Square(double edge) : base(edge, edge) {

    }
}
```

Note that the constructor is now empty, because `Edge` isn't really "stored". When you access it, it just returns the width.

P.S. I don't think `Edge` is a good name. I would call it `SideLength`.